# How to "pass" information from a custom cell class to a viewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell class which contains a slider which I would like to use to save an integer value (stored as a string). The value of the slider is saved to a global variable in the custom cell, and a save function in the viewController is supposed to save that value. However, it doesn't save the updated value. (I recognize that saving to a global variable and then using that global variable in a different view isn't a good idea, but I did not know how to pass the info... I have used `prepareForSegue` for other scenarios but there is no segue here... the slider is in a cell in the viewController). Here is the code:

```
var moneyValue: Int = Int()
var moneyAmount: String = String()
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var moneySlider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        moneyValue = Int(sender.value)
        moneyLabel.text = String(moneyValue)
        moneyAmount = moneyLabel.text!
    }
}//there is an initializer (not posted) that sets the original value to 0
```

Here is the overall viewController code:

```
class CreateVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate { 
            @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
                //save moneyAmount to DB
            }
}
```

The saving to the DB is very simple, but a value of "0" is always the value saved, regardless of the slider's position. "0" is the initial position of the slider, so I think that the problem is that the slider's updated value isn't being saved to the variable somehow. 1. How do I fix this and/or 2. what is the appropriate way to pass this information if the current set up isn't ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had edited this answer, according to the comments.

Define a protocol in cell.swift

```
protocol CellDelegate : class
{
    func cellDelegate(moneyValue: Int) -> Void
}
extension CellDelegate
{
    func cellDelegate(moneyValue: Int) -> Void {}
}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?

    var moneyValue: Int = Int()
    var moneyAmount: String = String()
    @IBOutlet weak var moneySlider: UISlider!
    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider)
    {
        moneyValue = Int(sender.value)
        moneyLabel.text = String(moneyValue)
        moneyAmount = moneyLabel.text!

        if delegate != nil {
            delegate?.cellDelegate(moneyValue: moneyValue)
        }
    }
}
```

then, implement this protocol in viewcontroller.swift. The value will be passed from cell to view controller.

```
class CreateVC: UIViewController, CellDelegate
{
    func cellDelegate(moneyValue: Int)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. Once you earn enough reputation you can post comments but until then, please do not post comments as an answer. Either delete this or edit it so it is an actual answer. A good answer will be more than one simple sentence. Clearly explain how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: @rmaddy It's not his fault posting comments takes more rep than answer (why?!). It's not "right", but this is the emergent behaviour of the site rules.

Comment: Now that you have posted an answer, please keep in mind that code-only answers are frowned upon here. It's best to explain the solution and then to backup the description with code. It's also best if the answer explains what was wrong with the code in the question when appropriate.

Comment: i tried this but i'm don't see the method cellDelegate(moneyValue: Int) being called in ViewController, so am i suppose to fetch the value from it in view controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
            class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

            var moneyValue: Int = Int()
            var moneyAmount: String = String()

            @IBOutlet weak var moneySlider: UISlider!
                @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
                    moneyValue = Int(sender.value)
                    moneyLabel.text = String(moneyValue)
                    moneyAmount = moneyLabel.text!
                }

// create action of 'button save' in your custom cell, whenever you clicked on button you get all the values of components here and save your values in your DB
// Now, you don't need to declare global variables,

            @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
                        //save moneyAmount to DB
                    }
        }
```

If you'r going to use your custom cell in multiple `UIViewController` then above method fails. Then do as below:

1. Use delegate and protocol [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)
2. Closures (Block callback) [enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: I understand the concept, but I can't have the save button in the custom cell class because it also does a lot of things with other values in the view, and so having it in the custom cell class would make it very complicated.

Comment: OK no problem, I thought you have save button. As now according to your problem, now go with the below options as I provides the link make delegate or closure as per your code compatibly.

Comment: As you know, objects of components which is in cell you always get either in 'cellForRow' method or in customCell method. If you do code in 'cellForRow' method , it increases the length of code in one single method and when you wanted to use same customCell for other VC then you have to again do the same code so take callback is the best approach for your problem.